# Send data over Bluetooth using GameKit crash

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gamekit

I'm trying to use the below method to send simple data through GameKit Bluetooth. However, when my 2 devices successfully connect and I tap the button to send, it just crashes at the last line showing "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". Any idea what's wrong?

```
- (IBAction)sendAction:(id)sender {
    // convert an NSString to NSData
    NSString *str = @"Yahooooo!!";
    NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [currentSession sendDataToAllPeers:data withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not managing the retain count of the currentSession variable properly.  Assuming that currentSession is a member variable, when you assign to currentSession, if it's not being returned by a method called alloc or copy, you need to retain it until you are done with it, at which point you should release it.

You should check out the Memory management Programming Guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html